# 2 positional arguments expected by 'NavigationBloc.new', but 0 found. Try adding the missing arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, sidebar, bloc

```
import 'package:aplikacja_mobilna/home/Sidebar/sidebarr.dart';
import 'package:aplikacja_mobilna/home/bloc.navigator_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SideBarLayor extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideBarLayor({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
                builder: (context, navigationState) {
              return navigationState as Widget;
            }),
            const SideBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I create a navigation between going to other pages. A sidebar was created, and when opening the sidebar, click on one of the items and the page that is clicked on should open

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What does `NavigationBloc` look like for example?